Hyper не выделяет нижние подчеркивания
Начал недавно пользоваться эмулятором терминала Hyper и столкнулся с проблемой, что при выделении текста он пропускает нижнее подчеркивание и следующий за ним символ. Вот примеры:

Такая же проблема образуется в NeoVim когда я открываю его именно через Hyper:

Версия Hyper - 3.4.1
Не нашел ни одного обсуждения или решения этой проблемы в интернете
Благодарю заранее!

Отправить им баг?

Ну да, точно, я об этом не подумал
